# Ionic 2 define menu on page component instead of root component

Tags: html, menu, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am having trouble trying to implement a simple menu in my Ionic 2 project. All of the examples I have seen online define the HTML for the menu within `app.html` and then only have a button with the `menuToggle` tag on the page that uses the menu.

Here's what I am trying to do. The root page of the app is a login page of sorts, called `HomePage`. this page is defined as `rootPage` in `app.ts` as seen below. After the user logs in, they are brought to the `SettlementPage` page. On this page, the user should be able to open a menu that displays a list of other settlements the user can travel to.

My problem is that I need to define the menu and its content from within the context of the `SettlementPage`, not the `HomePage`, which seems to be the way all of the examples do it. I am confused about how to go about doing this, since there is not much documentation on the topic. Specifically, I am confused about how the line `<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>` operates. What exactly does this bind the menu to? In all of the examples, `rootPage` is a member of the root component defined in `app.ts`. How would I go about binding a menu to a specific `Page` component?

One line of thinking I went down was that I needed to bind the menu to the `ion-content` section of this particular page's HTML. So, I added an ID field as in `<ion-content id="content">` and then tried to reference it with `<ion-menu [content]="content">` but that didn't seem to work. I also tried setting `this.rootPage = this;` within `settlement-page.ts` but that didn't work either.

I think I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding about how menus are supposed to be bound to Pages. Is it even possible to do this, or does a menu have to be defined on the root component and accessed elsewhere referring to some sort of ID?

Here is the relevant code from my project for reference:

`app.ts`:

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';

@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  platform: Platform;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

`settlement-page.html`:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle side="left">
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>
    {{settlement.name}}
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-menu side="left" [content]="mycontent">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Settlements</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let settlement of settlements" 
                       (click)="travelTo(settlement)">
          {{settlement.name}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-content>
  <p>Name: {{player.name}}</p>
  <p>Caps: {{player.caps}}</p>
</ion-content>

<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

`settlement-page.ts`:

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Player} from '../../providers/classes/player';
import {Settlement} from '../../providers/classes/settlement';
import {SettlementService} from '../../providers/services/settlement-service';
import {SqlService} from '../../providers/services/sql-storage-service';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/settlement-page/settlement-page.html',
    providers: [SqlService, SettlementService]
})
export class SettlementPage {
  private nav: NavController;
  private navParams: NavParams;
  private sqlService: SqlService;
  private settlementService: SettlementService;
  private player: Player;
  private settlement: Settlement;
  private settlements: Settlement[];
  private menu: MenuController;

  constructor(nav: NavController, navParams: NavParams, 
              sqlService: SqlService, settlementService: SettlementService,
              menu: MenuController) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.navParams = navParams;
    this.sqlService = sqlService;
    this.settlementService = settlementService;
    this.menu = menu;

    this.player = navParams.get('player');
    this.settlement = navParams.get('settlement');
    this.settlements = settlementService.getSettlements();
    //don't allow navigation to current settlement
    this.settlements.filter((value: Settlement) => value != this.settlement);
    console.log(this.menu.getMenus());
  }
}
```

On the final line, `this.menu.getMenus()` returns an empty array, which tells me that the menu I have defined in `settlement-page.html` is not being recognized. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Currently, the menu icon appears in the top left corner of the nav bar, but when I click on it a blank, transparent menu slides out from the left.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a few hours now and there seems to be nothing online about defining and using menus outside of the app's root component.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? If yes then please share the answer

Answer (score 4):

I followed the answer of Manu Valdés stated above but had to change a bit for ionic 2. What I did was:

Add to the page where menu is not necessary:

```
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public menu:MenuController) {
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }
  ionViewDidLeave(){
    this.menu.enable(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you ultimately want to do is have a menuless screen first, and then progress to a menu enabled page, just leave everything as default, don't do weird bindings, and just disable the menu in the homePage,  `this.menu.enable(false);`

Then on the lifecycle method `onPageDidLeave` of the same homePage, reenable the menu so it's availabe going forwards